# facebook - JavaScript sdk I am getting friends list without permission.. is this right?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been testing an app where my test user gave the app basic and read_friendlists permission. Later I went to my user account and removed the read_friendlist permission for the app but I am still able to get the list through the sdk. Is this a case of lag for my account settings? or can you always get friends list in the following manner without explicit permission?

```
 function authSuccess() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function (result) {
        if (result.data) {
            $.each(result.data, function (index, friend) {
                alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
            });
        }else{}
    });
}
```

Comment: ... check the privacy settings on the test account, not just the granted app permissions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read_friendlists`  [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) is for accessing a user's customised [Friend Lists](https://www.facebook.com/help/135312293276793/) at the `/USER_ID/friendlists` connection, not the list of friends at `/USER_ID/friends`

This is working as expected - check the [User documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) for a list of fields and connections of the User object and the permissions you need to access each (though the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) documentation covers a lot of that too)